# Access Form data-url Attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form tag set up like this:

```
<form data-id="213" method="post" onsubmit="javascript: startAjax(); return false;">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

When I submit the form I am running an ajax script to validate some stuff. How can I access the "data-id" attribute in my ajax script.

I have tried $(this).data("id") but it returns undefined. Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `this` is your form?

Comment: Show use the relevant javascript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `this` to `startAjax()` function

```
<form data-id="213" method="post" onsubmit="javascript: startAjax(this); return false;">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

JS

```
function startAjax(obj){
   var id = $(obj).data('id')
   //rest of your code
}
```

As you are already using jQuery. Then you should use [**.submit()**](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$(this).attr('data-id')
```

?

Comment: Why would this work when `$(this).data("id")` doesn't?

Comment: You would be surprised. My office only has jquery 1.4, as an Intern i cant update things, and for some reason I could only access data attributes in the form .attr("data-dayOrder"). We have IE8 but the latest Firefox but it still didn't work.

Comment: `$(this)` is not available in `startAjax()` scope, so there is no difference what method to use: `data()` or `attr()`. So this answer is totally wrong, don't know who could upvoted it.

Comment: I happened to come across some problems using "data" in the past to retrieve dom attributes that hadn't been previously stored with the same method, that's why I was suggesting this instead.

Comment: Hast, you are right, my mistake. Just followed the lead of the original poster and assumed $(this) was available on the scope

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `$(this)` to your `startAjax()` function (see @Satpal answer) or use jquery event (which is much better):

**HTML:**

```
<form data-id="213" method="post" id="my-form">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my-form").submit(function(e) {
        alert($(this).data('id');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```